# PHP GD - save part of image - one letter

Tags: php, image, copy, gd

Is there a way to copy an element from one image to other image? I know about imagecopy() function but this function can copy only standard shapes, for example: Rectangle, square. But what I have to do when I have these image:

[image]

and I want to copy only "O" letter in that way:

[image]

(look at the red border - it's important for me). Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Short answer is no. Using __gd__ you can only copy rectangular areas. However, using PNG transparencies that shouldn’t be a problem. If you really want to do more intricate work, you will need to manipulate the data directly (it’s accessible in PHP) but that’s not going to be easy.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Make all the pixels that are not blue into transparent pixels, then you will only be copying blue ones, surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell  PHP will only copy rectangular areas. In some image formats, you have the option of _transparent_ pixels, but they are sill there. In GIF, for example, one “colour” is nominated as a transparent colour, much like a blue-screen in filming. In PNG, there is an optional _alpha_ mask, which is a grey-scale map of how transparent each pixel is. In both cases, the actual pixels are still there, but you just don’t see them.